# Getting SIGABRT when freeing char pointer

Tags: c, string, char, malloc, free

This is how i allocate the space needed:

```
char *all_type_str;
...
all_type_str = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
```

setting string:

```
strcpy(all_type_str,"all");
```

setting it in a different array:

```
...
values[0].value = all_type_str;
```

and freeing values array:

```
for (i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
{
    free(values[i].value); //   <-- SIGABRT
}
free(values);
```

allocating values array:

```
values = malloc(sizeof(struct cnf)*adjArrSize);
```

using gdb i can see that i have a not null pointer with the wanted `"all"` string

but for some reason i get `SIGABRT` when trying to free the first place in the array.

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: We need to see how `values` is allocated and `arrSize` and it's full layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your pointer fall out of scope? Is this at the same function?
We can't tell unless we see the full code.